# Here Maps Routing

Tags: json, here-api

We are experiencing a problem while using service https://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/calculateroute.json
Since July 21, 2016, all attempts to use this service end-up with the following response: 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity)

We are using test plan (90-day trial of entire platform)

While searching for information on this issue, we have found that this problem also exists on your demo-page with the example of route calculation: https://developer.here.com/apiexplorer-v2-sample-data/template-rest-default/examples/enterprise-truck-route-from-a-to-b/index.html

What is the reason for this problem?
What solution can we apply to overcome this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `nokia.com` is not supported anymore, https://developer.here.com/news/20160310.

I suggest you to try https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/request-a-truck-route.html